# Bootstrap 3 .dropdown in .media object does not overflow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Drop down menu

[image: Drop down menu]

Have this drop down menu but it doesn't seem to show all of it's content, like it disappears half way.

```
            <div class="media-body">
          <h4 class="panel-heading" style="margin:0;">                <div class='btn-toolbar pull-right'>
              <div class='btn-group'>
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#pwr-accordion" href="#" class="btn btn-info">
                  <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>
                </a>
                <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle btn-large" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                  <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Add New Picture</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Update Power Info</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Delete Power</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </h4>
            <div class="panel-body">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, architecto itaque dignissimos asperiores ea commodi nam consequatur corporis sequi iure!
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please click on "Drop down menu" to see the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Bootstrap 3 ships with `overflow:hidden` on `.media` and `.media-body`. If you want to override that, you need to add the following to your custom CSS, making sure it loads after Bootstrap's:

```
.media, .media-body {
   overflow: visible
}
```

You can see it working here:

```css
div.media, div.media-body {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="media">
        <div class="media-left media-middle">
          <a href="#">
            <img alt="64x64" class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/64x64" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9InllcyI/PjxzdmcgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB3aWR0aD0iNjQiIGhlaWdodD0iNjQiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA2NCA2NCIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+PCEtLQpTb3VyY2UgVVJMOiBob2xkZXIuanMvNjR4NjQKQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEhvbGRlci5qcyAyLjYuMC4KTGVhcm4gbW9yZSBhdCBodHRwOi8vaG9sZGVyanMuY29tCihjKSAyMDEyLTIwMTUgSXZhbiBNYWxvcGluc2t5IC0gaHR0cDovL2ltc2t5LmNvCi0tPjxkZWZzPjxzdHlsZSB0eXBlPSJ0ZXh0L2NzcyI+PCFbQ0RBVEFbI2hvbGRlcl8xNWM2MTNiZWU3NCB0ZXh0IHsgZmlsbDojQUFBQUFBO2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OmJvbGQ7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsIEhlbHZldGljYSwgT3BlbiBTYW5zLCBzYW5zLXNlcmlmLCBtb25vc3BhY2U7Zm9udC1zaXplOjEwcHQgfSBdXT48L3N0eWxlPjwvZGVmcz48ZyBpZD0iaG9sZGVyXzE1YzYxM2JlZTc0Ij48cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iNjQiIGhlaWdodD0iNjQiIGZpbGw9IiNFRUVFRUUiLz48Zz48dGV4dCB4PSIxMi41NDY4NzUiIHk9IjM2LjUiPjY0eDY0PC90ZXh0PjwvZz48L2c+PC9zdmc+"
              data-holder-rendered="true" style="width: 64px; height: 64px;">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
          <h4 class="panel-heading" style="margin:0;">
            <div class='btn-toolbar pull-right'>
              <div class='btn-group'>
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#pwr-accordion" href="#" class="btn btn-info">
                  <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>
                </a>
                <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle btn-large" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                  <li><a href="#">Add New Picture</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Update Power Info</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Delete Power</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </h4>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, architecto itaque dignissimos asperiores ea commodi nam consequatur corporis sequi iure!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="media">
        <div class="media-left media-middle">
          <a href="#">
            <img alt="64x64" class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/64x64" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
              data-holder-rendered="true" style="width: 64px; height: 64px;">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
          <h4 class="panel-heading" style="margin:0;">
            <div class='btn-toolbar pull-right'>
              <div class='btn-group'>
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#pwr-accordion" href="#" class="btn btn-info">
                  <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>
                </a>
                <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle btn-large" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                  <li><a href="#">Add New Picture</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Update Power Info</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Delete Power</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </h4>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, architecto itaque dignissimos asperiores ea commodi nam consequatur corporis sequi iure!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If this doesn't fix your issue, it is caused by code which you are not sharing.
Consider adding a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue to your question, using the snippet tool (<kbd><></kbd> button).

Answer (score 0):

I think reason of this issues is z-index. please check z-index of dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Check the z-index. The z-index specifies which content is in front via stack order. See more info on z-index here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index?v=control